# Change font in whole application programmatically, based in user selection

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am developing an app in which the user selects, in the web, a font (he has about 3 or 4 choices). The app must have the selected font in the whole application, so I need to change it programmatically (no XML involved). I received the font selected by the user via a web service. I have searched the web, but all the solutions I have read need the usage of XML.

0- The app has some (3-4) .ttf files in assets folder

1- The user selects a font in the web.

2- Android app starts, and gets a String constant (or int) that represents the font selected by the user.

3- The Android app changes its font according to the user selection, in the whole application.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't know if it's the right way but i guess can be done using custom views and storing the required font in SharedPref and apply based on that.

Comment: So I should substitute all my Views in app to a custom View that has a setFont() method, right?

Comment: Yeah that can be done

Comment: One more approach i can think of is have multiple themes and have different font for each theme and setTheme(R.style.font1) in ur Application based on ur settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To programmatically change the font in the whole app you can try **Calligraphy** library

https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy

Initializing the font will be in the Application class so i believe you can achieve what you are asking for

```
 ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
        .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                    .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                    .build()))
        .build());
```

you can do something like

```
String fontPath;
if(userSelection == 0) { //userSelection value from the server
    fontPath = "fonts/FirstFont.ttf"
} else if (userSelection == 1) {
    fontPath = "fonts/SecondFont.ttf"
} else {
    fontPath = "fonts/ThirdFont.ttf"
}

ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
    .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
         new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
             .setDefaultFontPath(fontPath)
             .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
              .build()))
            .build());
```

I assumed you can retrieve the user selection from the server

Comment: Yes, that's right, I am going to get the user selection from server.

Comment: This looks fine. The server side is not done yet, so I cannot test it, but I am going to accept this answer despite I cannot test it, but looks ok. Thanks.

Comment: You can try it with static values and test if it changed the font of the app, explore the library and see if it fits your needs. Happy coding man